# Hide branches in Unity3D SpeedTree

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a tree Growth simulator in Unity3D for a project using SpeedTrees. I would like to be able to take the default SpeedTrees that come with Unity, and hide branches at certain times, and then show them again, to simulate branch growth. Is there a way to do this without paying for the SpeedTree editor? I was thinking maybe apply materials to the model that make parts of it invisible, but I'm not sure how to apply that to one branch at a time.